# Android - Add dynamic xml to layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want to merge between layout file and xml file.
But, my problem, is how can I do it dynamically.

I mean that I have general toolbar file that contains: my app icon, the activity name and linearlayout space for button. I want to merge this toolbar to each activity, so that all activity could put its own buttons in the linearlayout in the toolbar.

I have try to do that, I wrote toolbar file that called `toolbar.xml` in the `layout` folder.
And each activity included this toobar like that:  `<include layout="@layout/toolbar.xml" />`, but I do not know how to insert the buttons.

Can I do that with the xml of the activity only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add buttons from code (which I guess is what you want to do) you just need to have a container where your buttons shall be inserted into. You can just add `<LinearLayout>` to your layout XML file (ensure your layout got id, i.e.:

```
<LinearLayout>
   ...
   android:id="@+id/button_container"`
</LinearLayout>
```

Them, in your code create your button as any other object:

```
Button myButton = new Button( mContext );
```

then find your button container:

```
LinearLayout buttonContainer = findViewById(R.id.button_container);
```

and add your button to it:

```
buttonContainer.addView( myButton );
```

To find out more see [ViewGroup documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

Comment: It can be done with the xml only? I mean without involving java code.

Comment: Depens on what you really need (your question is not fully clear to me - "button space" menas you do not know what buttons will be there so you need to create it from code). XML files cannot be modified so if you need dynamically created button set then "no". Also `<include>` cannot be conditional so "no" again. But if you know what buttons it would be then you could create separate layout file **per each combination**. It is better to do that in code in such case

Comment: I meant that each activity has const buttons. i.e: main activity has add contact and settings buttons, contact activity has accept or cancel changes buttons. Each activity has const buttons and its depends the activity.